# Boost Asio: checking socket ability to be readable/writable

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

In my application I have to mix of both asio created sockets and native ones(coming from C posgresql library).

What I need is the ability to get notification out of boost's io_service class instance on the particular socket to be in non-blocking readable/writable state, but without performing an actual read/write(will be done by 3-rd party library), i.e. effectively doing only **select**()/**poll**()

Can it be achieved with passing 0 as buffer length to the function like **async_read_some**()?

I've made a quick test and indeed a call to **async_read_some**() with zero buffer length does call read event handler but I am not sure it is done after blocking in **select**()/**poll**() over the corresponding socket handle, waiting for the real "can read" state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is often referred to as reactor-style operations.

These can be obtained by providing [`boost::asio::null_buffers`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/null_buffers.html) to the asynchronous operations.  Reactor-style operations provide a way to be informed when a read or write operation can be performed, and are useful for integrating with third party libraries, using shared memory pools, etc.  The Boost.Asio [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/reactor.html) provides some information and the following example code:

```
ip::tcp::socket socket(my_io_service);
...
socket.non_blocking(true);
...
socket.async_read_some(null_buffers(), read_handler);
...
void read_handler(boost::system::error_code ec)
{
  if (!ec)
  {
    std::vector<char> buf(socket.available());
    socket.read_some(buffer(buf));
  }
}
```

Boost.Asio also provides an official [nonblocking example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.nonblocking), illustrating how to integrate with libraries that want to perform the read and write operations directly on a socket.

---

Providing a zero-length buffer to operations will often result in a no-op, as the operation's completion condition will have been met without attempting to perform any I/O.  Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b65699ccaa85b3c) the difference between the two:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

// This example is not interested in the handlers, so provide a noop function
// that will be passed to bind to meet the handler concept requirements.
void noop() {}

void print_status(
  const boost::system::error_code& error,
  std::size_t bytes_transferred,
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket)
{
  std::cout << "error: " << error.message() << "; "
               "transferred: " << bytes_transferred << "; "
               "available: " << socket.available() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

  // Create all I/O objects.
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 0));
  tcp::socket socket1(io_service);
  tcp::socket socket2(io_service);

  // Connect the sockets.
  acceptor.async_accept(socket1, boost::bind(&noop));
  socket2.async_connect(acceptor.local_endpoint(), boost::bind(&noop));
  io_service.run();
  io_service.reset();

  std::array<char, 512> buffer;

  // Reading into a zero-length buffer is a no-op and will be
  // considered immediately completed.
  socket1.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, 0), 
    boost::bind(&print_status,
      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
      boost::ref(socket1))
  );
  // Guarantee the handler runs.
  assert(1 == io_service.poll());
  io_service.reset();

  // Start a reactor-style read operation by providing a null_buffer.
  socket1.async_receive(boost::asio::null_buffers(),
    boost::bind(&print_status,
      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
      boost::ref(socket1))
  );
  // Guarantee that the handler did not run.
  assert(0 == io_service.poll());
  // Write to the socket so that data becomes available.
  boost::asio::write(socket2, boost::asio::buffer("hello"));  
  assert(1 == io_service.poll());
}
```

Output:

```
error: Success; transferred: 0; available: 0
error: Success; transferred: 0; available: 6
```

Comment: `null_buffers` has been deprecated since Boost 1.66.0: [_"(Deprecated: Use the socket/descriptor wait() and async\_wait() member functions.)"_](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/null_buffers.html)